# Is it possible to encapsulate a native method in a thread using ByteBuddy Advice mechanism?

Tags: java, byte-buddy, javaagents

I am trying to delay writing to a socket in a separate thread to simulate latency in the network stack using an javaagent. Using ByteBuddy, I managed to decorate the native `java.net.SocketOutputStream::writeSocket0`. However, doing so, I pause the current thread which is not what I want to achieve. To avoid this issue, I thought of creating a thread from which the native method can be called. Unfortunately, my knowledge of ByteBuddy remains rather limited and I didn't manage to find a way to achieve this. My best attempts looks like the code below:

```
//premain function
public static void premain(final String agentArgs, final Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    try{
        BootLoaderInjector.inject(DelayedExecutor.class);
        long duration = 100;

        new AgentBuilder.Default()
            .with(new ByteBuddy().with(Implementation.Context.Disabled.Factory.INSTANCE))
            .with(AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.NoOp.INSTANCE)
            .with(AgentBuilder.TypeStrategy.Default.REBASE)
            .enableNativeMethodPrefix("somePrefix")
            .with(AgentBuilder.Listener.StreamWriting.toSystemError().withErrorsOnly())
            .ignore(nameStartsWith("net.bytebuddy."))
            .type(named("java.net.SocketOutputStream"))
            .transform((transformer, typeDescription, classLoader, javaModule) ->
                transformer.method(named("socketWrite0"))
                    .intercept(
                        Advice.withCustomMapping().bind(Duration.class, duration)
                        .to(DelayInterceptor.class)
                )
            )
            .installOn(instrumentation);
    }
    catch (Throwable t){
        System.err.printf(t.getMessage());
    }
}

// interceptor class
public class DelayInterceptor {
    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static void intercept(@SuperCall Callable<?> caller, @Duration long duration) {
        DelayedExecutor.execute(callable, duration);
    }
}

// execute the intercepted method in a new thread with a delay
public class DelayedExecutor implements Runnable {
    private final Callable<?> callable;
    private final long delay;

    private DelayedExecutor(Callable<?> callable, long delay) {
        this.callable = callable;
        this.delay = delay;
    }

    public static void execute(Callable<?> callable, long delay){
        new Thread(new DelayedExecutor(callable, delay)).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(this.delay);
            this.callable.call();
        } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }
}
```

However, this fails because `@Callable` is not part of the `Advice` API.

Not using the advice seems to pose serious limitations. Indeed using MethodDelegation raises the following error:

```
Registration of auxiliary types was disabled: net.bytebuddy.implementation.auxiliary.MethodCallProxy@3206bfce
```

Is there a way to wrap a function call inside a block using the `Advice` API of ByteBuddy?

**Edit**

To add more clarity and to address the answer suggestion, here is the implementation of `BootLoaderInjector.inject` which shows how types are added to the bootloader classloader  relying on `ClassInjector.UsingUnsafe.ofBootLoader()`:

```
public class BootLoaderInjector {
    public static void inject(Class<?> targetClass) {
        try {
            ClassInjector.UsingUnsafe.ofBootLoader().inject(singletonMap(
                    new TypeDescription.ForLoadedType(targetClass),
                    ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.read(targetClass)
            ));
        } catch (Throwable e){
            System.out.println("Something went terribly wrong: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to register an `InjectionStrategy` to inject these required types into the targeted class loader. For the boot loader, this could for example be one `UsingInstrumentation`. More efficiently, but relying on JVM internal API, you could also use `UsingUnsafe`.

Comment: As usual, thanks a lot for the clear answer. I didn't know about the InjectionStrategy. So I added the following line when initializing the AgentBuilder: .with(AgentBuilder.InjectionStrategy.UsingUnsafe.INSTANCE). Unfortunately, using the methodDelegation I get the same problem. Could it be due to an interference with other initialization option I set? Thanks again.

Comment: After some tests, I realized that in the error stack trace, I had an issue with Context.Disable, so I removed it from the AgentBuilder, I do manage to perform the instrumentation now, but it seems that the class still isn't properly loaded within the application with the following message at runtime and not at instrumentation time: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/net/SocketOutputStream$auxiliary$LosFwLln. I have a feeling that this is the class that was created by the rebase, but not sure.

Comment: It likely is. Are you sure there is no instrumentation error? You need to register an `AgentBuilder.Listener` to see those. Also: Have you tried using the regular injection strategies and get the same error?

Comment: I did some investigation and the ```with``` part of ```new ByteBuddy().with(Implementation.Context.Disabled.Factory.INSTANCE)``` is the one creating the issue. However, without it, I cannot instrument the class java.net.SocketOutputStream. I decided to use ASM directly and it seems to do the job.